# Tensorflow - How to translate models into other languages

Tags: python, tensorflow, persian

I'm using tensorflow to classify images in a dataset. It's python api is so easy and useful. It gives me some english tags for each image when I use inception v3 model. I want to how I can translate these words to another language (e.g Turkish, Persian, ...) in its model.

Comment: Are you trying to get image to text or only text to text translation. https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/im2txt have a look here

Comment: I'm trying to get image to text.

Comment: Isn't it just dictionary translation of tag (class name)? Your training data is in English so the model output English tags. You can "fix" this by manually translate the tags in your data then replace the English tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you’re using something like https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/image_recognition
then the model returns a numerical representation of the label which it then turns into a text string using a look up table. In that example, I think they provide the look up table as a text file with a number and an object or short list of objects. You just need to translate the look up table then tie the numerical label to that text string. Maybe google translate can do that. The labels are objects or lists of objects (so not sentences).

Answer (score 0):

Try this link 
https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/tutorials/seq2seq/

Above link shows example for English to French or vice versa but you can train the model again for your requirements.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! To make your answer more useful, could you please provide the relevant sections from the link directly in your answer. Background is that content of links might change over time and your answer becomes useless then.